# What is the reason for converting a Mongoose query result to JSON before sending to client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose

I'm getting data with Mongoose and send it to Ajax on the client for being displayed:

```
Note.find({author: req.user._id}, function(err, notes) {
           // sending data
        }
```

If I send it as it comes

```
res.send(notes)
```

[I get back what seems like a nice JavaScript object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DG1zo.png) . And I can easily access it with

```
data[0]["note"]
```

Whereas if I convert the query result to JSON first

```
res.send(JSON.stringify(notes))
```

[I get a string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dbo0L.png), which I'd have to parse additionally. Why is this necessary, when the initial query result already enables me to use the data?

Comment: Because http is "HyperText Transfer Protocol", it can't deliver live objects.

Comment: @Teema, ah that makes sense. Yet it seems I received the object? What I got back on the client when I didn't convert to JSON seems to be the same as what I got back when I did convert to JSON on the server and parsed it with JSON.parse(data)?

Answer (score 0):

One common header that you need to set is the Content-Type of the response so that the client knows how to interpret the data the server sends in the body.

It's important that you set the Content-Type header to application/json, too.

```
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify(notes));
```

the client side framework see to the header of response and try to convert data to the 'Content-Type'. if your data is not JSON show to you text.